# Calculate Hessian of a "weird" function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

let be $L $ an invertible matrix,  $b \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$

and  $J: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $J(x)=\|L x\|_{2}^{2}+\mu x^{t} x-b^{t} x$

How do I calculate its hessian matrix?
I cant operate as a usual function and calculate its gradient and also i dont know what to do with that norm

Progress:

$\|L x\|_{2}^{2} =\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} (l_{i,j}\cdot x_{j})^2$

$\mu x^{t}\cdot x =\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu \cdot x_{i}^2$

$-b^{t} x = - \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_{i} \cdot x_{i}$

so $J(x)=\\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} (l_{i,j}\cdot x_{j})^2+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu \cdot x_{i}^2   - \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_{i} \cdot x_{i} $

so the gradient is

$\nabla J(x)=(\sum_{i=1}^{n} l_{i,1} + 2 \cdot \mu \cdot x_{1} - b_{1}, ..., \sum_{i=1}^{n} l_{i,n} + 2 \cdot \mu \cdot x_{n} - b_{n} )         $

and the Hessian is the diagonal matrix of $2 \cdot \mu$

Dunno if it is right and I also think there has to be an easier way of doing it, like operating with the vectors and matrix instead of deriving each variable on their own.

FINAL EDIT:

As some comments sugested(thank you all) i can write the function as :
$J(x)=x^tL^tLx +  \mu x^tx -b^tx$

So:

$ \nabla J(x)= 2(L^tL+I\mu)x-b$

and

$HJ(x)=2LL^t+2 I \mu$

Comment: What is $L$? The norm is only a function $N$. Use the chain rule.

Comment: "I cant operate as a usual function" Why not?

Comment: The function is not "weird" at all, it is a second degree polynomial, the simplest function without a trivial Hessian.

Comment: thanks for your comments, just edited op with my progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Hessian is the matrix of second partial derivatives $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$, the linear term will vanish. You can rearrange the second order term to:

$$(Lx)^t(Lx) + \mu x^tx = x^t(L^tL + \mu I)x.$$

Each second derivative will then select one of the coefficients of this second-degree homogeneous polynomial. Can you see your way to the end of the computation from here?

---

As for thinking of this in terms of matrices, think first of the derivative. Every linear function can be written as $p_1(x) = v^Tx$ for some vector $v$. The gradient of a smooth function $f$ at a point is defined as this vector for the best linear approximation to $f$ at that point.

Every homogeneous second-degree polynomial $p$ can be written as
$$ p(x) = x^THx $$
for some symmetric matrix $H$. The Hessian of a smooth function $f$ at a point is defined as this matrix for the best second-order approximation to $f$ at that point.

So now you see the root of the strategy to isolate the second order term.

Comment: yes! guess so. Many thanks.  What I dont completely understand is how derivation should be made with vectors without having to think it as multivariable

Comment: also, how can you sum $L^tL +\mu$ it should be $\mu I$?

Comment: @kieskk Sorry, an imprecise habit on my part. I edited to include the identity matrix, and an explanation of the strategy.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** When $h \to 0$, we have
\begin{equation}
J(x + h) = J(x) + \text{linear terms} + \|L h\|_2^2 + \mu h^t h
\end{equation}